# Docker - React app not reachable with nginx

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, nginx

I have backend express js, frontend react js . Express api reachable but not React

===> React Dockerfile :

```
FROM node:16 as client-build
WORKDIR /front
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 80

# Setup the server
FROM nginx
WORKDIR /front
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY --from=client-build /front/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

===> Backend Dockerfile :

```
FROM node:16

WORKDIR /back
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
CMD npm run start
```

===> docker-compose :

```
version: "3.8"

services:
    mongodb:
        image: mongo:3.6.8
        restart: unless-stopped
        ports:
            - "27017:27017"
        volumes:
            - db:/data/db
        networks:
            - backend
    back:
        depends_on:
            - mongodb
        build: ./back
        ports:
            - "9000:9000"
        networks:
            - backend
            - frontend
        restart: on-failure
    front:
        depends_on:
            - back
        build: ./front
        ports:
            - "80:9001"
        networks:
            - frontend
        restart: unless-stopped
volumes:
    db:
        driver: local

networks:
    backend:
    frontend:
```

I use docker on windows ps and on ubuntu server, both results are same.

localhost:9000 or domain.com:9000 -  backend reachable
but localhost / localhost:9001 / domain.com / domain.com / 9001 not reachable

Only when i run a curl on terminal with local ip (that i got from docker 192.172****) i get result but not from outside

I'm new at docker. My goal is make the frontend accessable via domain and api private. But for the very next step all i need is to access frontend via browser.

===> Nginx conf

```
user nginx;
worker_processes 1;

error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  _;

        location / {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index index.html index.htm;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
        }

        location /api/ {
            proxy_pass http://back:9000/api/;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What's in the `nginx.conf` file?  What error are you getting, and where are you getting it?  (There's a significant difference between Nginx trying to connect to `back:9000` and reporting an HTTP 503 error, and the browser app trying to connect to anything.)

Comment: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED - over browser // i updated my post nginx.conf is as its above

Comment: If your Nginx configuration is listening on port 80, that needs to be the second number in the `ports:` setting.  Do you have the `ports:` numbers swapped?  If `ports: ['9001:80']` then `http://localhost:9001/` will forward to port 80 in the container.

Comment: probably i got really tired i didnt realize that i assigned the ports as 80:9001 // Sometimes it happens. Thank you !